# Medium to Advance LINQ/EntityFramework Query question. taggings items

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

My objective is to be able to add tags to an item, i should be able to pass a CSV string of tag names, and if the item isn't already linked to a tag then it is linked.

**my code works as your see at the bottom of this message but I want to know if this is the most efficient way of doing. can this be done with less queries?**

A little database scheme info:

3 tables:
Tags, TaggedItems, ContentType

Tags table has: Name, TagID

TaggedItems table has: TagID, ContentTypeID, ContentTypePrimaryKey

ContentType table has: ContentTypeID, Name

the item is a list of tag names and a content type object are past to a method,
and as long as the a tag in the list isn't already linked to the content type object (i.e. in the taggedItems table) then add it.

```
    public void AssignTagsByNameToContentType(string csvOfTagNames, IContentType contentObject)
    {            
        string[] tags = csvOfTagNames.Split(',');

        //get me all the tags that hav been linked to this content object already (call to the DB:( )
        var existingTags = GetTagsForContentType(contentObject);

        //filter out the tags past that are already linked to this content object (call to the DB :( )
        var newTags = from t in tags
                      where !(from et in existingTags
                              select et.Name)
                             .Contains(t)
                      select t;

        //add the new tags to the content object, multiple calls to the DB :(
        foreach (var newTag in newTags)
        {
            taggedItemsRepo.SaveTaggedItem(new TaggedItem() { 
                ContentObjectPK = contentObject.ID, 
                ContentTypeID = GetContentTypeIDFromSession(contentObject),
                TagID = tagsRepo.GetTagByName(newTag)
                );                
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest creating a new savetaggeditems method that takes more than one tag and inserts them all before calling savechanges().

Comment: this is a very valid point and i have implemented your suggestion. i have re-worked the code and i currently profiling it. i will post soon.